# How to def a function inside a Class

Tags: python, function, class

So guys, sorry if this question posted again. i dont know, why convert_int() is undefined even i've defined it. please reply this if you can answer. Thank you guys :)

```
class Abc(object):
    def __init__(self,words):
        self.words = words
    def convert_int(s): #here the problem, @staticmethod can't solve this
        try:
            return int(s)

        except ValueError:
            return s
    def test(self):
        words = self.words
        words = convert_int(words)
        return words

f = Abc("12345")
print(f.test())
```

Comment: Use `def convert_int(self, s):`, or decorate with `@staticmethod`. See https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/ for example.

Comment: Because you neither passed `self` in the function definition, nor called it with `self.convert_int(words)`

Comment: can you post your answer, so that i can checklist your question. thanks sir for answer my question

Comment: `words = convert_int(words)` here, `convert_int` does not mean the `convert_int` method of the same class, it means a *global* `convert_int`. You need `self.convert_int` for the same reason that you needed `self.words` on the previous line. If you want to use a `staticmethod` then you still need to say where that method is, using the class name: `Abc.convert_int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `convert_int` as for an instance method in the class.

```
class Abc(object):
    def __init__(self,words):
        self.words = words

    def convert_int(self, s): #updated
        try:
            return int(s)
        except ValueError:
            return s
    def test(self):
        words = self.words
        words = self.convert_int(words) #updated
       return words
f = Abc("12345")
print(f.test())
```